# raspberry fails to mount root filesystem on boot

Tags: boot

After an upgrade of raspbian I rebooted the system and it printed the following message:

"mounting /dev/mmcblk0p2 on /root failed: No such device"

After that an emergency shell (busybox) appeared. When I mounted the partition it worked without any problems. I changed the filesystem to vfat because I thought some kernel modules were missing, but it didn't help.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Probably quickest to reimage and start again.

Comment: What OS are you using? Raspberry Pi OS hasn't used `/dev/mmcblk0p2` for years! Did you fiddle with `cmdline.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to joan, I compared my system to a standard image and realized, that I forgot to change the rootfstype in /boot/cmdline.txt